# How to do multiple replacements with Solr DIH RegexTransformer?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am using Solr DataImportHandler with RegexTransformer and for a certain field I'd like to replace different patterns with different values.  Say, replace Smith with Miller and John with Joe.  A single replacement is easy:

```
<field column="text" regex="Smith" replaceWith="Miller"/>
```

But how to do the second part, replace John with Joe?

Note this is not asking for a fancy regex but rather how to apply more than one substitution on a single field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Quite simple really:

```
<field column="text" regex="Smith" replaceWith="Miller"/>
<field column="text" regex="John" replaceWith="Joe"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, You can use `groupNames` to specify ordered substitutions. Refer to the [original issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1061)

Example from [Solr Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer):

```
<field column="fullName" regex="Mr(\w*)\b(.*)" groupNames="firstName,lastName"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this creates the fields firstName and lastName.  Not what I want.